# How can I hide all <h2>'s except the first one?

Tags: html, css

How can I hide all `<h2>`'s except the first one?

```
<div class="holder">
  <h2>SOme heading</h2>
  <h2>Some Heading<h2>
  <h2>Some Heading<h2>
  <h2>Some Heading<h2>
  <h2>Some Heading<h2>
</div>
```

I am familiar that we can use something like:

```
p:nth-child(2)
{
  display:none;
}
```

But not sure how to hide all except the first one.  Can someone point me in the right direction? Would like something that is cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one option using the [**adjacent sibling selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/DbRU7/)

```
.holder h2 + h2 {
    display:none;
}
```

Probably your best option as `+` is [**supportted by IE7+**](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2)

Selectors such as `nth-child`/`:not` only **[work in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)**

Comment: That worked!  would that be cross browser compatible?

Comment: would this be possible via JQuery?

Comment: @ariel Sure. Do you want me to write something..?

Comment: If I were to use the Adjacent one how different would the css selector look?

Comment: @ariel Here [is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Pekd2/) of 3 different selectors, all of which work. They will all work in IE6+ .. pretty sure it will also work in IE6, though I have no way of testing it.

Comment: thanks can you also share the other CSS solution you mentioned where it will compatibile cross browsers? I am having issues using JQuery in my page due to other JS conflicts.  Would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: @ariel The one posted in my answer is your best option, `.holder h2 + h2` it will be supported in IE6+.

Answer (score 2):

```
h2:nth-child(n2) {
   display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sacha/full/cAJEo

**EDIT:** This link can also be used to do any `nth-child` testing

Answer (score 2):

you could do this:

```
#parent h2{
    display: none;
}

#parent h2:first-child{
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mWn2R/

Answer (score 1):

```
h2:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xtaG/1/)

Here's an option using the `:not` pseudo-selector combined with the `:first-child` pseudo-selector.

```
div.holder h2:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be other tags between headings, with modern CSS we can write it as

```
h2:not(:first-of-type) { display: none; }
```

or

```
h2:nth-of-type(n+2) { display: none; }
```

To make the code compatible with IE8, we can use the following, similarly to JoshC's answer:

```
.holder h2 ~ h2 { display: none; }
```

But why is it necessary to have many invisible headings in the code? It seems to be not good for search engines...